# Cannot index a user input that exists in a dictionary array

Tags: arrays, dictionary, indexing, python-3.8

I've got a user input that allows you to input whatever name you're looking for, with that user input, I also want to grade that value and give it a label, but I'm having trouble indexing the user input.

```
Stud = {
    "Emily": "55",
    "Jaden": "67",
    "Shifrah": "99",
    "Laszlo": "73",
    "Miguel": "33",
    "Raphael": "78",
    "Olivia": "21",
    "Daniel": "89",
    "Josiah": "34",
    "Tyrese": "79",
}

GradeBound = [
    ['A', 90],
    ['B', 80],
    ['C', 70],
    ['D', 60],
    ['E', 50],
    ['U', 0]
]



studCount = len(Stud)

studSel = str(input("Who are you looking for?"))

if studSel in Stud:
    print('found!')
    

else:
    print('no')
```

I've tried `Stud.index(studSel)` but it simply does not allow indexing in a dictionary.

To reiterate, I want the user to input a student, to which I'd want to index the user input (if found in the dictionary) and compare it the gradeBound array, returning a grade.

Comment: Do you realize that unlike sequences (e.g. lists), which are indexed by a range of numbers, dictionaries are indexed by keys?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may change some lines, for example it's better to change grade type in `Stud` array from `string` to `int`. just remove quotations. but here is the solution without doing this change, only

```
Stud = {
    "Emily": "55",
    "Jaden": "67",
    "Shifrah": "99",
    "Laszlo": "73",
    "Miguel": "33",
    "Raphael": "78",
    "Olivia": "21",
    "Daniel": "89",
    "Josiah": "34",
    "Tyrese": "79",
}

GradeBound = [
    ['A', 90],
    ['B', 80],
    ['C', 70],
    ['D', 60],
    ['E', 50],
    ['U', 0]
]

studCount = len(Stud)

studSel = str(input("Who are you looking for?"))

if studSel in Stud:
    print('found!')
    grade = int(Stud[studSel])
    print(grade)
    upperlimit = []
    lowerlimit = []
    for gb in GradeBound:
        if grade < gb[1]:
            upperlimit.append( gb[1] )
        else:
            lowerlimit.append( gb[1] )
    upper,lower = min(upperlimit), max(lowerlimit)
    for gb in GradeBound:
        if upper in gb:
            gbu = gb[0]
        if lower in gb:
            gbl = gb[0]
    print("the grade is between",gbl,gbu)
else:
    print('no')
```